# spring @autowired nullpointer

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a Spring @Autowired annotation in a ManagerBean. But my annotation is null, Where is de error?

This is My bean

```
package es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.controlador;

import.....

@ManagedBean(name = "kk")
@RequestScoped
public class PruebaBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 654564654L;

   String                    a;

   String                    b;

   @Autowired // This var is null, Why?
   private PersonaServicio   personaServicio;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
   }

   public PruebaBean() {
      this.a = "1";
      this.b = "Raúl";
   }

   public List<Persona> getPersonas() {
      // this.personaServicio is null, Why?
      return this.personaServicio.obtenerPersonas();
   }        
}
```

This is my interface

```
package es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.negocio.servicio;

import.....    

public interface PersonaServicio {

   public List<Persona> obtenerPersonas();

}
```

And its implementation

```
package es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.negocio.servicio.impl;

import.....    

@Service
public class PersonaServicioImpl implements PersonaServicio, Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 8035927808046807526L;

   private PersonaDAO        personaDAO;

   public PersonaServicioImpl() {

   }

   public PersonaDAO getPersonaDAO() {
      return this.personaDAO;
   }

   public void setPersonaDAO(PersonaDAO personaDAO) {
      this.personaDAO = personaDAO;
   }

   @Override
   public List<Persona> obtenerPersonas() {
      // Is not important for this example
      return null;
   }

}
```

Now the Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg" />

<h:head>
    <title><h:outputText value="hi" /></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
        <p:dataTable value="#{kk.personas}" var="persona" emptyMessage="Sin personas">
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{persona.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                <h:outputText value="#{persona.nombre}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Apellido">
                <h:outputText value="#{persona.apellidos}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and to finish the applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja"/>   

    <context:annotation-config  />      

</beans>
```

The error is (by Tomcat v7):

```
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @34,81 value="#{kk.personas}": Error reading 'personas' en el tipo es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.controlador.PruebaBean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:832)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:814)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:290)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:252)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:87)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'personas' en el tipo es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.controlador.PruebaBean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:184)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.controlador.PruebaBean.getPersonas(PruebaBean.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    ... 48 more
```

Thank you all for your time

Comment: Try to change this line in your applicationContext.xml:    <context:component-scan base-package="es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja.negocio.servicio"/> base-pakage must point to your package with service interfaces.

Comment: Subpackages are automatically scanned, so the configuration is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you told spring to scan this package? The code seems fine so it should be that you are not telling spring to scan the classes. This happens because adding annotation only, does not fix or facilitate the dependency injection, Spring needs to know where to look for.

You can use `@ComponentScan("yourPackage")` on the configuration class of your spring application to instruct spring to scan.

`@Service, @Component` etc annotations add meta description. 
Spring only injects instances of those classes which are either created as bean or marked with annotation.

**EDIT**
Create a class like the follwoing

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"your package"})
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
//your code here
}
```

Comment: I do not understand Niku Hysa. tell me what should I do.

Comment: I think this is effectively the same as what he is doing in the applicationContext.xml `<context:component-scan base-package="es.juntadeandalucia.capder.plja"/> `

Comment: Yes but in that way it is too difficult to debug. Through java you can debug better

Answer (score 0):

To most directly answer you question I think you need to add `@Controller` to the `PruebaBean` class.

I'm not sure how that will work if you are also use something like a JEE server, which the `@ManagedBean` implies, but that may be a separate topic

Comment: OK, my bean now it is:

`@ ManagedBean(name = "kk")` <br/> 
`@ Controller <br/> 
@ RequestScoped <br/> 
public class PruebaBean implements Serializable {<br/><br/>
But, I have the same error`

Comment: You may want to try to try the java configuration listed above by @NikuHysa . You may also want to put a debug in the PostConstruct and/r the constructor of `PersonaServicioImpl`. This [link](http://www.journaldev.com/4096/primefaces-spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial) describes a similar setup and may be helpful.